# How to make a select image in form

Tags: html, forms, select, bourbon, neat

I need a form with images selectables, I´ve serched in google and I try with select option but this not working

Can you give any idea to resolve this please?

I am using bourbon & neat (SASS)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would make check boxes into images, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0c26tqd7/1/

**edit** I added a red border on checked check boxes in the fiddle

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name='thing1' id="thing1"/><label for="thing1"></label>
```

**css**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input#thing1[type=checkbox] + label
{
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/");
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: +1 Great Answer. Additional, `$('#thing1').css('background-image', 'url(image.ext)');` could help, to set the image dynamicly

Comment: Also, one more thing to note: If OP wants a one-at-a-time selection, change to radio buttons with the same `name`